# MSAL returns null user after successfully acquiring tokens with auth code

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

In the following code the GetUserAccount returns null user even though the precedeeing AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode did return both an access and an id token. I would expect it to be non-null. In my later code silent acquire obviously fails because the user is still null. What am I missing?

```
var code = ctx.Code;
string signedInUserID = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, ctx.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
var capp = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    clientId,
    String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}.onmicrosoft.com/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", "b2cdom", "B2C_1_BasicSUSI"
),
    "https://localhost:44368/",
    new ClientCredential(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Secret"]),
        userTokenCache,
        null
);
capp.ValidateAuthority = false;
var tokens = await capp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
    code,
    new string[] { "https://mrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/webapiill/read" }
);
var user = await capp.GetAccountAsync(signedInUserID);
```

Comment: You might consider updating to the latest version of MSAL (3.0.4-preview) and update everything to the new [builder pattern](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications#instantiating-a-confidential-client-application-from-code) there have been a lot of cache fixes between v2 and v3, and see if it repros there as well.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to 3.0.4-preview and use of builder pattern. I am not clear on where and how I plug in my user token cache. In the last line of the docs you reference, where is the _tokenCache created? How does the conf client app know to use it? (I don't see referneces to the cache anywhere in the WithXyz APIs.